# Convert datetime format in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert a datetime format,convert function have not returned correct value.

here is my data

```
2015-09-07 07:00:01.0730000 +08:00
```

my query

```
 select convert(varchar(16), '2015-09-07 07:00:01.0730000 +08:00', 103)
```

but it returns

```
2015-09-07 07:00
```

Expected result

```
07/09/2015 07:00
```

Comment: Remember that dates in SQL Server don't have a "format", the only time a format is used is when you convert them to text. I strongly advise you don't convert them at all, other than apply a display format in your user interface.

Comment: @DavidG . . . Regardless. Either the conversion should generate an error or it should be in the format of 103 (DD/MM/YYYY).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well yes, but the reason that is happening is because CONVERT is expecting a DATETIME, casting that string to a DATETIME makes it work.

Comment: For example: `select convert(varchar(16),CAST('2015-09-07' AS DATETIME),103)`

Comment: @DavidG . . . As I understand the construct, the *result* is a `varchar()` in the format of 103, and the second argument should be implicitly converted to a `datetime`.  However, SQL Server seems to be doing something different.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i guess that the implicit conversion is causing SQL Server to use different logic and effectively ignores the 103 parameter unless given an explicit DATETIME object.

Comment: @GordonLinoff From the docs: When *expression* is a date or time data type, *style* can be one of the values shown in the following table.

Comment: thanks guys, finally I go for cast!!!, good study today

Comment: Style 103 is being ignored because you're converting a string to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mystery is explained in the documentation:

> When expression is a date or time data type, style can be one of the
>   values shown in the following table. Other values are processed as 0.
>   . Beginning with SQL Server 2012, the only styles that are supported
>   when converting from date and time types to datetimeoffset are 0 or 1.
>   All other conversion styles return error 9809.

That is, the style is based on the *expression*, not on the target data type.  I find this a bit counter-intuitive.  But, it means that the 103 is being ignored, because the argument is a string and not a date/time data type.

Hence, you are just converting a string to a string, so nothing happens.  This is perhaps clearer with this example:

```
select convert(varchar(255), 'hello world', 103)
```

This has nothing to do with a `datetime` and it returns `'hello world'` (see  [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3042)).

I find this curious behavior, but it is documented so the behavior is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
select convert(varchar(100),cast('2015-09-07 07:00:01.0730000 +08:00' as datetime),103)
        +' '+
       SUBSTRING('2015-09-07 07:00:01.0730000 +08:00',12,5)
```